# What's difference between <foo></foo> and null in JAXB?

Tags: java, web-services

I am have created a Java Webservice application which uses JAXB. When I test my application using SoapUI and I send a SOAP message like `<foo></foo>`, it will convert to `0`, but if there's no `<foo>` tag in my SOAP message, it will convert to `null`. Why is `<foo></foo>` not converted to `null`? How can I change it?

```
@WebMethod
public void test(Integer foo) {
    System.out.print(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`null` generally indicates "unknown". Since foo isn't present, there is absolutely NO information about it. You can't assign a default 0, because that might be absolutely wrong/catastropic. All you can do is say "I don't know", which boils down to null. On the other hand, `<foo></foo>` means that foo is present and is empty, which does generally boil down to a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAXB 2.2 then you can specify the `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` annotation at the parameter level to have the XML represented as `xsi:nil="true"`.

```
@WebMethod
public void test(@XmlElement(nillable=true) Integer foo) {
    System.out.print(foo);
}
```

Comment: I am using JAXB2.1.  If I put @XmlElement as you told me, compile error show up.

Comment: @Chris - The ability to set the `@XmlElement` annotation at the parameter level was introduced in JAXB 2.2.